# BB10 WiFi/Bluetooth Detection

Tags: bluetooth, wifi, blackberry-10, blackberry-qnx

I'm doing a bit of research and I was hoping to get some clarification on the availability and functionality of APIs for `BB10`.

**What I'm trying to accomplish:**

I'm trying to create a `BB10` application that will record a value or wake up an application when the user walks into range of a `Bluetooth` or `WiFi` signal. The `WiFi` and `Bluetooth` signal is completely controlled and configured by me, so any specifications can be defined to serve the application.

**My understanding of BB10:**

My understanding is that you can wake up a `BB10` application through a push service, but as of right now you cannot run an application as a background task.

I looked through the `BB10` API reference and couldn't find any information on scanning for WiFi networks, or for Bluetooth devices.

**Question**

Is it possible to wake up an application and record a value when you walk into a `WiFi` signal, or when you get in range of a `Bluetooth` device?

So far my research has shown: No, but please prove me wrong.

Comment: Normally when headsets go out of range, they try to connect for next 1-2 mins and then stop connectin to the last connected device.If you can control the bluetooth signal of your device, pair and connect both the device, once phone(BB) is out of range , make your other device to connect previously paired device(BB10) always

Answer (score 1):

Currently, you can't have any form of background application, but it's planned for August: http://developer.blackberry.com/native/downloads/roadmap/